# JavaScript not working on Ruby on Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to follow [this (somewhat outdated) Ruby on Rails tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lets-create-an-intermediate-level-ruby-on-rails-application-d7c6e997c63f) and I'm having trouble getting any JavaScript to work. More specifically, I have this js file:

modal.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    // when a post is clicked, show its full content in a modal window
    $("body").on( "click", ".single-post-card, .single-post-list", function() {
      console.log('test');
      var posted_by = $(this).find('.post-content .posted-by').html();
      var post_heading = $(this).find('.post-content h3').html();
      var post_content = $(this).find('.post-content p').html();
      var interested = $(this).find('.post-content .interested').attr('href');
      $('.modal-header .posted-by').text(posted_by);
      $('.loaded-data h3').text(post_heading);
      $('.loaded-data p').text(post_content);
      $('.loaded-data .interested a').attr('href', interested);
      $('.myModal').modal('show');
    });
  });
```

that should be applied onto this html.erb file:

_modal.html.erb

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div  class="modal myModal" 
      tabindex="-1" 
      role="dialog" 
      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="posted-by"></span>
        <button type="button" 
                class="close" 
                data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
                aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="loaded-data">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
            <div class="interested"><a href="">I'm interested</a></div>
          </div><!-- loaded-data -->
        </div><!-- modal-body -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then there are also these html.erb files:

_post.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-3 single-post-card" id=<%= post_path(post.id) %>>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="post-text">
        <%= truncate(post.title, :length => 60) %>
      </h4>
      <div class="post-content">
        <div class="posted-by">Posted by <%= post.user.name %></div>
        <h3><%= post.title %></h3> 
        <p><%= post.content %></p>
        <%= link_to "I'm interested", post_path(post.id), class: 'interested' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- card -->
</div><!-- col-sm-3 -->
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'posts/modal' %>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="side-menu"  class="col-sm-3">
    </div><!-- side-menu -->

    <div id="main-content" class="col-sm-9">
      <%= render @posts %>
    </div><!-- main-content -->

  </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Project01</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

    
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
    <div class="mainPage">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The application.js file:

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"


//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
```

[Whole project can be found here.](https://github.com/panoskrip/saas_project01)

I've tried including the js file in various places through out my app, as well as writing it inside  tags in the html file, as well as other answers found on stackoverflow but with no success.

Comment: "this (somewhat outdated) Ruby on Rails tutorial" - very outdated, it's for rails 5. find tutorial for rails 7.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a specific error or issue you are facing. "I'm having trouble getting any JavaScript to work" is not an actionable issue. What exactly does not work? What exactly are you observing?

Answer (score 0):

Try including javascript_include_tag `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload"%>` on your application.html.erb file